# How to solve $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I already know that it is equal to $\ln(1-z)$, but I need to prove that.

Comment: I have just edited. You need to remember to put the math parts between \$ symbols. Otherwise it does not display properly and you attract downvotes!

Comment: @G.Sassatelli that's not at all a duplicate of the linked to question.

Comment: @quid Sorry, I was so sure it had already been asked that I did not notice one had the real variable, while the other did not.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli the main difference is not real vs complex. The difference  is that the q you linked to asks for a particular method, which makes it more narrow and more complicated. But I suppose it is a dupe of some other post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the domain of convergence of the serie you have : $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n} \Rightarrow f'(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}$$
Then you can try to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

The main steps are:

- Take the derivative of the series.
- Find its closed form. (Note it is just a geometric series.)
- Find the antiderivatives of the closed form.
- Select the correct antiderivative by determining the involved constant via summing the series at some point (for example $0$).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sum of a geometric series with constant ratio $\;r,\,\,|r|<1\;$ , then

$$\frac1{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\;,\;\;\;|z|<1$$

Now remember you can differentiate and integrate elementwise within the convergence radius.