# How can I solve $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} \cdot z^n}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

The answer is given. It is equal to $\ln(1 + z)$.
Can you help me solve it?

Comment: For future reference, if you are able to answer your own question, do not edit it and leave the answer. Answer it below instead. Also, your power series converges only when $|z|<1$ (keep that in mind).

Comment: @par I think he means he only has the answer, but not the solution.

Comment: Basically the same as your other question [How to solve $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774093/how-to-solve-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(z)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}z^n}{n}$.

Differentiating both sides, we have: $$S'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}z^{n-1}$$

Simplifying: $$S'(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nz^n=\frac1{1-(-z)}=\frac1{1+z}$$

Integrating both sides: $$S(z)=\ln(1+z)+C$$

Substituting $z=0$ will yield $C=0$.

Comment: +1 but a discussion on the convergence of $S(z)$ and where the manipulations applied make sense may be in order :-)